# Ошибка при компиляции c++ программы в clang: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: mac, clang, c++

Исходный код:

```
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.h>

int main()
{       
        Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
        Fl_Box box(0, 0, 200, 200, "Hey, I mean, Hello, World!");

        window.show();

        return Fl::run();
}
```

Сообщение компилятора:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Fl::run()", referenced from:
      _main in fltk_test-5lyBgN.o
  "Fl_Box::Fl_Box(int, int, int, int, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in fltk_test-5lyBgN.o
  "Fl_Widget::~Fl_Widget()", referenced from:
      Fl_Box::~Fl_Box() in fltk_test-5lyBgN.o
  "Fl_Window::show()", referenced from:
      _main in fltk_test-5lyBgN.o
  "Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int, int, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in fltk_test-5lyBgN.o
  "Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()", referenced from:
      _main in fltk_test-5lyBgN.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Команда:

```
clang++ ./fltk_test.cpp
```

Пробовал флаги -lfltk, -I/usr/local/include/FL/, -L/usr/loclal/lib/, -m32, -m64, все безрезультатно. Библиотека FLTK установлена, проверял каталоги /usr/local/include и /usr/local/lib, файлы на месте. Не могу выяснить причину ошибки. Использую OSX 10.9, компилятор CLANG 5.0, библиотеку FLTK 1.3.2. Команда g++ -lfltk ./fltk_test.cpp выдает следующее (простите за флуд):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::repeat_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFAttributedStringCreate", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CFDataCreate", referenced from:
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::dnd() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFDataGetBytePtr", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFDataGetLength", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFDictionaryCreateMutable", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CFDictionarySetValue", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CFGetRetainCount", referenced from:
      bmProviderRelease(void*, void const*, unsigned long) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_delete_offscreen(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
  "_CFNumberCreate", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      delete_timer(MacTimeout&) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      q_set_window_title(NSWindow*, char const*, char const*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Paged_Device::print_window(Fl_Window*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_mac_set_about(void (*)(Fl_Widget*, void*), void*, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "_CFRetain", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
  "_CFRunLoopAddTimer", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFRunLoopGetCurrent", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      delete_timer(MacTimeout&) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFRunLoopRemoveTimer", referenced from:
      delete_timer(MacTimeout&) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFRunLoopTimerCreate", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFRunLoopTimerGetNextFireDate", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFRunLoopTimerSetNextFireDate", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::repeat_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringCreateArrayBySeparatingStrings", referenced from:
      createPopupAccessory(NSSavePanel*, char const*, char const*, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings", referenced from:
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringCreateCopy", referenced from:
      fl_mac_set_about(void (*)(Fl_Widget*, void*), void*, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithBytes", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:
      q_set_window_title(NSWindow*, char const*, char const*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Sys_Menu_Bar::doMenuOrItemOperation(Fl_Sys_Menu_Bar::menuOrItemOperation, ...) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      createPopupAccessory(NSSavePanel*, char const*, char const*, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCharacters", referenced from:
      q_set_window_title(NSWindow*, char const*, char const*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCharactersNoCopy", referenced from:
      fl_mac_width(unsigned short const*, int, Fl_Font_Descriptor*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringGetCharacters", referenced from:
      cocoaKeyboardHandler(NSEvent*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding", referenced from:
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CFUUIDCreate", referenced from:
      Fl_Preferences::newUUID() in libfltk.a(Fl_Preferences.o)
  "_CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes", referenced from:
      Fl_Preferences::newUUID() in libfltk.a(Fl_Preferences.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::create_offscreen_with_alpha(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_create_offscreen(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextGetAlphaInfo", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel", referenced from:
      CGBitmapContextToNSImage(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_read_image(unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_read_image.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow", referenced from:
      CGBitmapContextToNSImage(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_read_image(unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_read_image.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextGetData", referenced from:
      CGBitmapContextToNSImage(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_delete_offscreen(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_read_image(unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_read_image.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextGetHeight", referenced from:
      Fl_X::q_fill_context() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CGBitmapContextToNSImage(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_read_image(unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_read_image.o)
  "_CGBitmapContextGetWidth", referenced from:
      CGBitmapContextToNSImage(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_read_image(unsigned char*, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_read_image.o)
  "_CGColorCreate", referenced from:
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray", referenced from:
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      Fl_X::CGImage_from_window_rect(Fl_Window*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::create_offscreen_with_alpha(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_create_offscreen(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateWithName", referenced from:
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      Fl_X::CGImage_from_window_rect(Fl_Window*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::create_offscreen_with_alpha(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      fl_create_offscreen(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
  "_CGContextAddArc", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::circle(double, double, double) in libfltk.a(fl_vertex.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::arc(int, int, int, int, double, double) in libfltk.a(fl_arci.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::pie(int, int, int, int, double, double) in libfltk.a(fl_arci.o)
  "_CGContextAddLineToPoint", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::line(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextClipToRect", referenced from:
      Fl_X::q_begin_image(CGRect&, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CGContextClipToRects", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::restore_clip() in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGContextClosePath", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::loop(int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::loop(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::polygon(int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::polygon(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::end_polygon() in libfltk.a(fl_vertex.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::end_complex_polygon() in libfltk.a(fl_vertex.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::pie(int, int, int, int, double, double) in libfltk.a(fl_arci.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextDrawImage", referenced from:
      Fl_Paged_Device::print_window(Fl_Window*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_Bitmap*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
  "_CGContextFillPath", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::polygon(int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::polygon(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::end_polygon() in libfltk.a(fl_vertex.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::end_complex_polygon() in libfltk.a(fl_vertex.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::circle(double, double, double) in libfltk.a(fl_vertex.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::pie(int, int, int, int, double, double) in libfltk.a(fl_arci.o)
  "_CGContextFillRect", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::rectf(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::point(int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGContextFlush", referenced from:
      Fl::flush() in libfltk.a(Fl.o)
      Fl_X::flush() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::end_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_CGContextMoveToPoint", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::line(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
      fl_delete_offscreen(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
  "_CGContextRestoreGState", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_release_context(Fl_X*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_clear_clipping() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_end_image() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Paged_Device::print_window(Fl_Window*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(int, char const*, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::origin(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextRotateCTM", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(int, char const*, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::origin(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::scale(float, float) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::rotate(float) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_CGContextSaveGState", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_clear_clipping() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_begin_image(CGRect&, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_begin_offscreen(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(int, char const*, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::origin(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::scale(float, float) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextScaleCTM", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_fill_context() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_begin_image(CGRect&, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::nesw_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_X::nwse_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::origin(int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::scale(float, float) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextSetLineCap", referenced from:
      fl_quartz_restore_line_style_() in libfltk.a(fl_line_style.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineDash", referenced from:
      fl_quartz_restore_line_style_() in libfltk.a(fl_line_style.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineJoin", referenced from:
      fl_quartz_restore_line_style_() in libfltk.a(fl_line_style.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      fl_quartz_restore_line_style_() in libfltk.a(fl_line_style.o)
  "_CGContextSetRGBFillColor", referenced from:
      Fl::dnd() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::color(unsigned int) in libfltk.a(fl_color.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char) in libfltk.a(fl_color.o)
      Fl_X::help_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_X::none_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_X::watch_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_X::nesw_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor", referenced from:
      Fl::dnd() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::color(unsigned int) in libfltk.a(fl_color.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char) in libfltk.a(fl_color.o)
  "_CGContextSetShouldAntialias", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::rect(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextSetTextMatrix", referenced from:
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CGContextSetTextPosition", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::xyline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::yxline(int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::line(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      ...
  "_CGContextStrokeRect", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::rect(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_fill_context() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::q_begin_image(CGRect&, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(int, char const*, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_X::watch_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_X::nesw_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      Fl_X::nwse_cursor_image() in libfltk.a(fl_cursor.o)
      ...
  "_CGDataProviderCreateWithData", referenced from:
      Fl_X::CGImage_from_window_rect(Fl_Window*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
      fl_create_bitmask(int, int, unsigned char const*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
  "_CGDataProviderRelease", referenced from:
      Fl_X::CGImage_from_window_rect(Fl_Window*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
      fl_create_bitmask(int, int, unsigned char const*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
  "_CGDisplayBounds", referenced from:
      screen_init() in libfltk.a(screen_xywh.o)
  "_CGDisplayScreenSize", referenced from:
      screen_init() in libfltk.a(screen_xywh.o)
  "_CGEventSourceKeyState", referenced from:
      Fl::get_key(int) in libfltk.a(Fl_get_key.o)
  "_CGGetActiveDisplayList", referenced from:
      screen_init() in libfltk.a(screen_xywh.o)
  "_CGImageCreate", referenced from:
      Fl_X::CGImage_from_window_rect(Fl_Window*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::draw(Fl_RGB_Image*, int, int, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
  "_CGImageMaskCreate", referenced from:
      fl_create_bitmask(int, int, unsigned char const*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
  "_CGImageRelease", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::copy_offscreen(int, int, int, int, CGContext*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_Double_Window.o)
      innards(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, void (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned char*), void*) in libfltk.a(fl_draw_image.o)
      Fl_RGB_Image::~Fl_RGB_Image() in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
      Fl_RGB_Image::uncache() in libfltk.a(Fl_Image.o)
      fl_delete_bitmask(CGImage*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
      Fl_Bitmap::~Fl_Bitmap() in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
      Fl_Bitmap::uncache() in libfltk.a(Fl_Bitmap.o)
      ...
  "_CGImageRetain", referenced from:
      Fl_X::CGImage_from_window_rect(Fl_Window*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CGRectContainsRect", referenced from:
      Fl_Widget::damage(unsigned char, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl.o)
  "_CGRectEqualToRect", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::clip_box(int, int, int, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGRectIntersection", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::intersect_region_and_rect(flCocoaRegion*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::not_clipped(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::clip_box(int, int, int, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGRectIsEmpty", referenced from:
      Fl_Window::make_current() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::intersect_region_and_rect(flCocoaRegion*, int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::not_clipped(int, int, int, int) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::clip_box(int, int, int, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGRectUnion", referenced from:
      Fl_Graphics_Driver::clip_box(int, int, int, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_rect.o)
  "_CGWindowLevelForKey", referenced from:
      -[FLDelegate windowDidResignKey:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate windowDidBecomeKey:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::make(Fl_Window*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_CTFontCreateForString", referenced from:
      fl_mac_width(unsigned short const*, int, Fl_Font_Descriptor*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTFontCreateWithName", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_width(unsigned short const*, int, Fl_Font_Descriptor*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTFontGetAscent", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTFontGetDescent", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_width(unsigned short const*, int, Fl_Font_Descriptor*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTLineCreateWithAttributedString", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTLineDraw", referenced from:
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTLineGetImageBounds", referenced from:
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_CTLineGetTypographicBounds", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_GetCurrentProcess", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_GetFrontProcess", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSApp", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      DataReady::DataReadyThread(void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_ready() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_wait(double) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLTextView insertText:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLTextView doCommandBySelector:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "_NSBeep", referenced from:
      fl_beep(int) in libfltk.a(fl_ask.o)
  "_NSDefaultRunLoopMode", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_ready() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_wait(double) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSDeviceRGBColorSpace", referenced from:
      CGBitmapContextToNSImage(CGContext*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSDragPboard", referenced from:
      Fl::dnd() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSFilenamesPboardType", referenced from:
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::make(Fl_Window*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSStringPboardType", referenced from:
      -[FLView performDragOperation:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::make(Fl_Window*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSWindowDidMoveNotification", referenced from:
      -[FLDelegate applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSWindowWillCloseNotification", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_NSZeroPoint", referenced from:
      Fl_X::make(Fl_Window*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributedString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBitmapImageRep", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBox", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCursor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDictionary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFont", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSGraphicsContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenu", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLMenuItem in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLApplication in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLaboutItemTarget in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLopenDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLsaveDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenPanel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPopUpButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPrintInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPrintPanel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSProcessInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSavePanel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSScreen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSThread", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser_MAC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLMenuItem in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLApplication in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLaboutItemTarget in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLMenuItem in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSTextView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PMGetAdjustedPageRect", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::printable_rect(int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::start_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMGetFirstPage", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::start_job(int, int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMGetLastPage", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::start_job(int, int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMGetOrientation", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::margins(int*, int*, int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::start_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMGetPageFormatPaper", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::margins(int*, int*, int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::start_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMPaperGetMargins", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::margins(int*, int*, int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
      Fl_System_Printer::start_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::start_job(int, int*, int*) in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMSessionBeginPageNoDialog", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::start_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMSessionEndDocumentNoDialog", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::end_job() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMSessionEndPageNoDialog", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::end_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMSessionError", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::end_job() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PMSessionGetCGGraphicsContext", referenced from:
      Fl_System_Printer::start_page() in libfltk.a(Fl_Quartz_Printer.o)
  "_PasteboardClear", referenced from:
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardCopyItemFlavorData", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardCopyItemFlavors", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardCreate", referenced from:
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardGetItemCount", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardGetItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardPutItemFlavor", referenced from:
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_PasteboardSynchronize", referenced from:
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_SameProcess", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_SetFrontProcess", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_X::make(Fl_Window*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_TransformProcessType", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_UTTypeConformsTo", referenced from:
      Fl::paste(Fl_Widget&, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      CFString in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLApplication in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLWindow in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTextView in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FLDelegate in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLApplication in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "_kCFAllocatorDefault", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::copy(char const*, int, int) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::dnd() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCFAllocatorNull", referenced from:
      fl_mac_width(unsigned short const*, int, Fl_Font_Descriptor*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCFRunLoopDefaultMode", referenced from:
      Fl::add_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      delete_timer(MacTimeout&) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB", referenced from:
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCTFontAttributeName", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      Fl_Quartz_Graphics_Driver::text_extents(char const*, int, int&, int&, int&, int&) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCTForegroundColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      fl_mac_draw(char const*, int, float, float, Fl_Graphics_Driver*) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_kCTKernAttributeName", referenced from:
      Fl_Font_Descriptor::Fl_Font_Descriptor(char const*, int) in libfltk.a(fl_font.o)
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      DataReady::DataReadyThread(void*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_ready() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_wait(double) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      fl_mac_flush_and_wait(double, char) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLTextView insertText:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLTextView doCommandBySelector:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[FLWindow initWithFl_W:contentRect:styleMask:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLView init] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
  "_objc_msgSend_fixup", referenced from:
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_objectAtIndex_ in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_count in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_class in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_isKindOfClass_ in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_isEqualToString_ in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
  "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
      fl_open_display() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate windowDidMove:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      update_e_xy_and_e_xy_root(NSWindow*) in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate windowDidResize:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      -[FLDelegate applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:] in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::x() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      Fl::y() in libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Пример результата команды "nm /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a":

```
…
/usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o):
…
000000000000ced9 s L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_99
                 U _CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent
…
/usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(Fl_cocoa.o):
…
000000000000ced9 s L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_99
…
                 U _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex
…
/usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.o):
…
0000000000001103 s L_.str9
                 U _CFAttributedStringCreate
…
```

Команда "file /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a" выдает следующий результат:

```
/usr/local/lib/libfltk.a: current ar archive random library
```

Comment: это ошибка линкера, судя по всему. попробуйте все-таки убедиться что вы линкуетесь с нужными файлами\библиотеками.

Comment: A почему таг gcc, когда компилятор clang? Кстати, что g++ -lfltk ./fltk_test.cpp говорит?

Comment: SoloMio, как можно убедиться в этом? dzhioev, таг gcc потому что целью проекта clang является создание замены gcc, и таг clang я увы не нашел. Комманда g++ -lfltk ./fltk_test.cpp, в прочем как и комманда clang++ -lfltk ./fltk_test.cpp (судя по-всему g++ - это alias для clang++) выдает сообщения об ошибках, которые я привел выше.

Comment: @6i96rother, ну судя о количеству ошибок от линкера, вы явно либо линкуетесь с чем-то не тем, либо не линкуетесь с тем что нужно. Что гоаорит документация по либе которую вы пытаетесь заюзать?

Comment: @6i96rother, зайдите в каталог, куда установлена FLTK и наберите ls -a. Какие там есть файлы .lib, .so или .a?

Comment: SoloMio, документация говорит использовать команду: CC  ... -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk, результат тот же. Файлы в каталоге с библиотекой имеют расширение ".a".

Comment: @6i96rother, посмотрите у Вас есть файл /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a ?

Если есть, посмотрите командой `nm` есть ли в нем Ваши unresolved.

Иначе, задача найти файл (.a или .so, например, используя find и grep) в котором есть эти символы и убедиться, что это библиотека (скажем, командой file).

Comment: Эти символы есть в файле libfltk.a, пример того что я нашел и результат команды file добавил в текст вопроса выше.

Comment: @6i96rother, этой библиотеке для работы (сборки исполняемого модуля) нужна еще какая-то другая, в которой и определены Ваши *unresolved*.

Видите, в ней (libfltk.f)

                 U _CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent

т.е. она сама ссылается на `_CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`. 

--

Определенные внешние символы отмечены в выводе `nm` буквами `T` или `D`, как для .a, так и .so. 

Правда, .so м.б. "стрипнута", тогда для просмотра символов в ней можно использовать, например, `objdump -T`.

IMHO, скорее всего у Вас нужные библиотеки не установлены. Ищите зависимости в инете.

Comment: Оказалось требовался Cocoa framework. Опция "-framework Cocoa" решила проблему. Всем спасибо за помощь!